# How to determine the time taken to complete a Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to include query statistics (i.e. records returned and elapsed time) in my Index views (similar to Google's).  I found the records returned, but am having difficultly locating the elapsed time.

I'm using Rails3 beta and the will_paginate plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Rails Footnote plugin](http://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes/) does this by registering itself with ActiveRecord as a connection adapter. Here's the [relevant source code](http://github.com/josevalim/rails-footnotes/blob/c7a75e43a87c778e45d922cbf628faa3445ca31e/lib/rails-footnotes/notes/queries_note.rb) from that project that should enable you to get started.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **mongrel** It displays all the queries in your terminal.

to install mongrel

"gem install mongrel" command